# Class and variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, namespaces

I have a question about some code,
this is a part of my code

Why `App.Font` and `App.FontSize` don't change?
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

[[enter image description here]
python 3

Comment: Change to `App.Font=listaCaratteri.get(`

Comment: @stovfl  but I want App.Font=listaCaratteri.get()  only when I press the Ok button. for this I use a new variable

Comment: See the **EDIT 2** of the answer, don't mix `global _font` with `local _font`. With  OOP use **only** `self._font`.

Comment: Ok for global variable  but   I don't  use the self parameter because _font  and  _size are internal to the method...

Comment: *"are internal to the method"*: Variable in a `function` are destroyed after exiting the `function`.

Comment: *"I want App.Font=listaCaratteri.get() only when I press the Ok button."*: Using `App.Font=listaCaratteri.get(` **is** inside the **OK Button** function. You don't need **all** the other **temp** vaiables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indentation. you're basically creating an empty class as you're missing a level of indentation.

**EDIT0** code indentation was due to not using code-blocks formatting of SO, please read the formatting [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to prevent this in the future.

**EDIT1** after your edit a new issue popped up, you create a class but you also need to instantiate an object. I suggest you go over the basics [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)

**EDIT2** no usage of the `self` parameter. If you want to change values of an object, use `self.variable = 'something'`

```py
    self._font="Arial"
    self._size="11"
```

```py
    def _fontFunc(event):
        self._font=listaCaratteri.get(tkinter.ANCHOR)
    def _sizeFunc(event):
        self._size=listaDimensioni.get(tkinter.ANCHOR)
```

```py
    def ok():
        self.Font = self._font
        self.FontSize = self._size
        print(self.Font, self.FontSize)
```

Comment: No. it is not an indentation problem.

Comment: the indentation in the sample provided does not look correct though. Can you provide a correctly indented code sample? Also, the self parameter is the actual issue. see the doc I linked in my answer

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot